# Print 1 to 1000 with out using loop

Tags: c

i see the question on a c++ programming context, i check for a solution and one of my friend give me this code its works perfect but i can't understand it's logic and also how it's works. i asked to him about it but he also don't know how the program is actually works, i think he is also take this solution from  somewhere. Anybody can explain the logic behind this i mean in the line
 `(&main +` `(&exit - &main)*(j/1000))(j+1);` ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main(int j) {
  printf("%d\n", j);
  (&main + (&exit - &main)*(j/1000))(j+1);
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can not recursively calling `main` in C++.

Comment: Thanks for your quick replay. i try it in c++ but it will not work but in c its works perfectly.but i don't know how its works .i mean its logic

Comment: Is this a standard`main` signature?

Comment: Seems like this code is "cheating" by using a recursive function call to create the counting loop (it's not an explicit loop, but there's still a loop there). Still, nice solution.

Comment: The pointer subtraction is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Anonymous it's a solution of a contest, I think it's meant to be full of undefined behavior :)

Comment: @G0BLiN, the point of the problem is to cheat.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It works as follows:

Performs the `int` division `j/1000`, which will return `0` always while `j` is smaller than `1000`.
So the pointer operation is as follows:

```
&main + 0 = &main, for j < 1000.
```

Then it calls the resulting function pointed by the pointer operations passing as parameter `j+1`.
While `j` is less than `1000`, it will call main recursively with parameter one more than the step before.

When the value of `j` reaches `1000`, then the integer division `j/1000` equals to `1`, and the pointer operation results in the following:

```
&main + &exit - &main = &exit.
```

It then calls the `exit` function, which finishes the program execution.

Comment: does the exit function must be written explicitly? or it can be deduced from the main?

Comment: The exit function is from the C std library, defined in stdlib.h.

Comment: It basically "linearly interpolates" the difference from the `MAIN` function to the `EXIT` function, with `integer-division` so that the switch from `A to B` is *instantaneous* once `1001` has been reached - and the integer is increased each time from the *recursive call* of `MAIN`.

Answer (score 4):

I go with the explanation already given but it would be easier to understand if written as below:

```
void main(int j) {
   if(j == 1001)
      return;
   else
   {   
      printf("%d\n", j); 
      main(j+1);
   }   
}
```

The above code does the same as already written code.

Comment: Realy this is more simple than the above .but logic is different

Comment: The idea is the same though.  The one you have has just been obfuscated, this is the canonical way to do recursion :- though you wouldn't usually use `main` to do it as it technically isn't a valid `main` signature iirc

Comment: really this is more simple method rather than above one. thanks for your replay

Comment: @ArunPrasanth np. The idea behind this is recursion and this would make you understand the code easily instead of the code which you have posted